# Windows Phone support in Socket.IO ( nodejs )

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have developed a mobile chat application using phonegap, jQuerymobile, nodejs(socket.io) . It is working good in android and iphone without any code modification. Now client wants the same to be ported to Windows Mobile Phone 7.I changed some code to make it work on Windows Mobile phone. Every functionality is working well except socket.io . And in http://socket.io#browser-support , There is no Windows mobile in their supporting platform list (as in attached) . Please help me out ...[image]

Comment: What isn't working with it? Given the fact that it supports IE 5.5+ on the desktop, I doubt there should be any big problem with IE9 on Windows Phone. What kind of problems are you running into?

Comment: @FurDworetzky . The application is not sending socket id to server (node) . I guess socket.emit() event itself not firing in windows phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 7.5/7.8 is based on IE9, it doesn't have all of its features - unfortunately, **WebSockets are not supported**.

To confirm this, I ran the Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 emulators and directed Internet Explorer to http://html5demos.com/web-socket.

WP7 (IE9) showed 'Sockets not supported' and Windows Phone 8 (IE10) showed 'Socket open'.